# Nimbus gamepad d-pad mappings?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gamepad

I can't figure out how are mapped d-pad buttons on the SteelSeries Nimbus gamepad.

I tested all buttons and all axes that Unity 3D can listen to, but the d-pad didn't responded for any of them.

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got response from SteelSeries support:

> The Nimbus controller is an iOS device, so that would explain why it's only working on iPad.

So that's it. On Apple devices it works fine, on the Android ones it works "somehow", but it's not officialy supported.